# Problems using find and cp to copy just .jpg files from a LOT of directories to one new path

Tags: macos, bsd

I tried the search, but couldn't find the answer to my specific problem.
When I use,

find /recovered_files "*.jpg" -type f -exec cp {} /out \;

to copy all .jpg files from directories within the /recovered_files directory, the /out directory gets filled with every single file (jpg, txt, xml etc etc) from within the source directories.
Can anyone please explain wherein my stupidity lies, pleeeeeease???

Many thanks, Mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing at the moment is equivalent to calling `cp /dir/dir/dir/file.jpg /out` for each file, which will copy the file into `/out`. Thus, all of the files are being put into the same directory.

`rsync` allows filters to select only certain files to be copied. Change `from` and `to` to the appropriate directories in the following:

```
rsync -r from/* to --include=*.jpg --filter='-! */' --prune-empty-dirs
```

Credit to [this post](http://blog.mudflatsoftware.com/blog/2012/10/31/tricks-with-rsync-filter-rules/) for this solution.

Edit: changed to `rsync` solution. Original as follows:

```
find from -name "*.jpg" -type f -exec mkdir -p to/$(dirname {}) \; -exec cp --parents {} to \;
```

You should replace `from` and `to` with the appropriate locations, and this form won't quite work if `from` begins with `/`. Just `cd` to `/` first if you need to. Also, you'll end up with all the files inside `to` underneath the entire directory structure of `from`, but you can just move them back out again.

Comment: That works like a charm! You Sir, are a wonderful man, and I thank you for your time and expertise!!! Thank You!

Comment: Np. Glad to have helped. Please accept the answer if you think it answers the question.